# Add marker to OSMdroid 5.5 map

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I want to add markers to my OSMdroid map. I am using OSMdroid **version 5.5**. The [official tutorial](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library) suggests the following code:

```
//your items
ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
items.add(new OverlayItem("Title", "Description", new GeoPoint(0.0d,0.0d))); // Lat/Lon decimal degrees

//the overlay
ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem> mOverlay = new ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem>(items,
    new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
    //do something
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
        return false;
    }
}, mResourceProxy);  // <----- where to get this object from?
mOverlay.setFocusItemsOnTap(true);

mMapView.getOverlays().add(mOverlay);
```

However, I don't know where to get the `mResourceProxy` object from. All websites I found about this topic (including OSMdroid's GitHub page) are making use of the `DefaultResourceProxyImpl` class, which is deprecated since version 5.2.

Does anyone know how to add marker versions >= 5.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I found out how to use it. The `ItemizedOverlayWithFocus` doesn't require a ResourceProxy at all. So you can use one of the following constructors:

```
public ItemizedOverlayWithFocus(Context pContext, List<Item> aList, OnItemGestureListener<Item> aOnItemTapListener) { ... }

public ItemizedOverlayWithFocus(List<Item> aList, OnItemGestureListener<Item> aOnItemTapListener, Context pContext) { ... }

public ItemizedOverlayWithFocus(List<Item> aList, Drawable pMarker, Drawable pMarkerFocused, int pFocusedBackgroundColor, OnItemGestureListener<Item> aOnItemTapListener, Context pContext) { ... }
```

This is how I adjusted the code from my question to make it work:

```
//your items
ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
items.add(new OverlayItem("Title", "Description", new GeoPoint(0.0d,0.0d))); // Lat/Lon decimal degrees

//the overlay
ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem> mOverlay = new ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem>(
    this, items,  //  <--------- added Context this as first parameter
    new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
    //do something
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
        return false;
    }
});  // <----- removed the mResourceProxy parameter
mOverlay.setFocusItemsOnTap(true);

mMapView.getOverlays().add(mOverlay);
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up, I'll update the tutorial

Comment: Second constructor worked for me. Thanks. Please update the tutorial. I searched for several hours to get this one

Comment: Now the official tutorial has neither context nor proxy - only two parameters. But the ItemizedOverlayWithFocus constructor still needs 3...